# DefaultJwtParser: how to merely decode the JWT? (no secret key, no validation)

Tags: java, jwt, jjwt

I don't want to verify the JWT using the secret key (which I don't have), I only want to decode the JWT and read the payload. Can this be achieved using jsonwebtoken.io:jjwt? It seems like there is a method missing in the API.

Of course, I could split-&-Base64-decode the token myself but it feels like the most basic functionality one would expect from a JWT-library; hence I suspect I am missing something.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
int i = jws.lastIndexOf('.')
String withoutSignature = jws.substring(0, i+1);
Jwt<Header,Claims> untrusted = Jwts.parser().parseClaimsJwt(withoutSignature);
```

You can 'chop off' the last 'part' after the last period character ('.'), which is the JWS signature.And then read that JWT as a 'normal' JWT (non-JWS).

What you are asking for is to ignore the signature on a valid JWS and read the JWT header and body anyway. This violates the JWS specification, and because of that JJWT does not support it.

This is taken from this [github issue](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/issues/135), which I guess is same as you are facing.

Comment: As for a workaround, I have one already. Your answer makes it clear tho the library actually (and on purpose) does not provide the functionality.

Comment: This is really bad approach, just use the auth0 library as @Blink is saying lower

Answer (score 4):

Maybe use the Auth0 library instead?

```
DecodedJWT jwt = JWT.decode(token);
jwt.getToken();
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
  <artifactId>jwks-rsa</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Example taken from https://medium.com/trabe/validate-jwt-tokens-using-jwks-in-java-214f7014b5cf

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use another library, it can be done as accepted answer here: [How to decode JWT token to get details of Header and Payload using nimbus-jose-jwt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696416/how-to-decode-jwt-token-to-get-details-of-header-and-payload-using-nimbus-jose-j)

Repeating the answer here: 
dependency:
`com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:<version>` 
usage:

```
/**
 * accessToken: the JWT string text.
**/
private String parseJWT(String accessToken) {
    try {
        var decodedJWT = SignedJWT  // or PlainJWT or EncryptedJWT
                           .parse(accessToken);
        var header = decodedJWT.getHeader().toString();
        var payload = decodedJWT.getPayload().toString();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid token!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the `JWTParser.parse(token)` of the `com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:{version}`:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
            <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>9.37.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

```java
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Map;

import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWT;
import com.nimbusds.jwt.JWTParser;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        String token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJZRU9iU1ZKdWZsem9WYW1KX05EbnZUbFA1SVNRVXNaRzRBVUZlWDFGZVFrIn0.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.NF0MzYSVkfDTo4YT8wmyibeY-D14C9J1kpCa5EUTRXQbdZX3Wbo053UsqlMMV6NVdG7jjQb1sG3So-nL-H6MLZyg0nmnfsmcnR5j315I6NCqGuJnMXxmbVxqUQViLW1lenJDGkDk2IOr2uJDcdTUR6pSemhnaXKOY47vEJ5dTTlvS73rJ1FQHKEv3kj50SjhgBSzRNuR7Ejghfnnp5kEXSekv40hLFXhE4Som_ZJ8IsYzTOvBMPnbYa5STNgprhcOlvmeiswXDrtyH2udd4qxxURivX7VAVT-Qt8_ozvGyQr7V4u5f4NRq-5i-SVYJtIjqwQOxnUrUMjzF1IDtCqow";
        JWT jwt = JWTParser.parse(token);
        Map<String, Object> claims = jwt.getJWTClaimsSet().getClaims();

        for (String key : claims.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s\n", key, claims.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

The `nimbus-jose-jwt` is also used by the `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:jar:6.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:9.24.4:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
```

BTW, I also tried to use the `io.jsonwebtoken`, but it seems that it required to verify the signature of the token. Such as *The JWS header references signature algorithm 'RS256' but the compact JWE string is missing the required signature.*